# How to get my custom checkout pane to save to order?

Tags: commerce

I am having a hard time with the commerce examples module. Specifically, I am having a problem with the Checkout Pane Example module

I am trying to understand how I get the values from the fields in example pane to a field on the order

I realize, I must be missing something fundamental here.

In the example checkout pane, they have a field called Nickname

I created a field Nickname on the order, and I get the checkout pane for Nickname

I noticed that my custom field is field_nickname, does that have any bearing on this?

The only other topic I have been able to find about this is here - http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/2401/custom-checkout-pane, an no one has answered this question either.

Thanks in advance!

As a site builder looking to learn how to better understand the code, I think a solution to this would help a lot of people.